# Unable to install Fabric on OSX using recommended Homebrew and pip. Xcode is latest version

Tags: macos, homebrew, fabric, pycrypto

I've been trying for two days to figure this out now.  I have the latest version of OSX and Homebrew.  I followed a tutorial that had me install pip via Homebrew and then it was recommended to install Fabric from Homebrew with:

```
brew install Fabric
```

But the formula for Fabric is gone from Homebrew.  Yes, I ran an update too.  So I followed yet another tutorial that advised me to install via pip.  pip install fabric

And it fails in all kinds of ways involving pycrypto.  Here's the pip log.  Aren't Macs supposed to make life easier?

```
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 241, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1277, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 622, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-DDW_Gb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto
```

Comment: Do you mean `pip install fabric`?  You can't install Fabric with `brew`.

Comment: If you are trying top install on the global scope, which I assume you are, and you have not changed the `/usr/local` owner to your user, you need to `sudo pip install fabric`

Comment: I did try sudo, of course.  For the sake of not letting this thread die, I never got Fabric installed on my Mac.  Xcode (yes, I have the latest version) seems to be the issue.  Actually, there are many things I can't seem to install on my Mac.  Sadly.

Answer (score 3):

So it was:

```
pip install fabric
```

It wasn't working for me previously because I was on Mac OSX and no one ever told me I had to have `Command Line Tools` installed to actually do anything useful with the Mac (this really should be better emphasized as it's taken me until December to finally install Fabric due to compliation errors until I installed those tools).